# Program complexity classes

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

Basically I am struggling to come to grips with operation counting and Big-O notation. I understand it is possibly one of the harder parts of computer science to understand and I have to admit I am struggling with it. Could anyone give me some help with these examples, and possibly any further help/links with Big-O?

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
     { for (j = i; j < N; j++)
          { sequence of statements }
     }
```

Here I would say the complexity is O(N²) - Quadratic

```
int m = -9
for (j = 0; j < n; j+=5)
     {
     if (j<m)
          {
          for (k = 1; k <n; k*=3)
               {some code}
               }
     }
```

Here I would also say is O(N²). The first loop takes N and the second loop takes N so I would say the answer is O(N*N) which is equal to O(N²).

Any help and advice for further understanding would be great!!

Comment: you are not specifying what you dont understand

Comment: It looks as though the second one is linear, since the outer loop will execute `O(N)` times, and `j` is never less than `m` (so the inner loop never executes at all). You're correct about the first one, though. (And were the `if` in the second example to disappear, you _would_ be correct about that as well.)

Answer (score 2):

The first is indeed `O(n^2)`, as you suspected, assuming the 'sequence of statements' is `O(1)`.

However, the second part of code is `O(n)`, since the condition `j < m` is never met - and thus, the outer loop only iterates itself without actually doing nothing. The inner loop is not even reachable.

As side note, some compilers may actually optimize the second part of code to run in `O(1)` by just setting the end values of variables, but this is not the point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The second example is complexity `O(N)`.

```
int m = -9
for (j = 0; j < n; j+=5)
{
    if (j<m)
    {
        // this never executes; m is negative and j is positive
    }
}
```

Comment: May I just ask what happens to j in the line `j+=5`?

Comment: The value of `j` increases by 5 after each iteration, and the `j` loop kicks out when it's no longer less than `n`.  The expression `j += 5` is executed after each iteration.  Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

First example:
The inner loop executes N times when i = 0, N-1 times when i = 1, and so on...
You can just calculate the number of steps the for loops execute

> (N) + (N - 1) + (N - 2) + ... + 2 + 1
>
> steps = N(N+1)/2 = (N^2 + N) / 2
>
> 1. N <=> 1 |add the left to the right| => N+1
> 2. (N - 1) <=> 2 |add the left to the right| => N+1
> 3. (N - 2) <=> 3 |add the left to the right| => N+1 . . . N

What does the big-O nation means?

> F(N) = O(G(N)) means that |F(N)|<= c*|G(N)| where c > 0

It means that the G(N) function is an upper bound on the grothw rate of the function. F(N) could not grow faster than G(N).

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw this out here: if we assume that the `j<-9` clause is a mistake and ignore it, then your second example has two nested loops. However the inner loop is actually *multiplying* `k` times 3. So this makes this inner loop O(log n). Which makes the pair of loops O(n log n). I'm not sure this is *the* answer, but you asked for further understanding, so... you know... maybe that's further.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, also on a further note I would really suggest you to go through a single lecture in the series of introduction of algorithms. Believe me you won't need to look any further.
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/